# PostgreSQL - error in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT par.id, par.title, cod.id AS id_codebook, cod.title AS title_codebook
FROM catalog_parameter_codebook cod
JOIN catalog_parameter par ON (par.id=cod.id_parameter)
JOIN catalog_parameter_product_value_parameter_codebook_mm codmm ON (cod.id=codmm.id_parameter_codebook)
JOIN catalog_parameter_product_value pv ON (pv.id=codmm.id_parameter_product_value)
JOIN catalog_product p ON (p.id=pv.id_product)
WHERE p.state=2 AND p.hidden=0 AND par.type=2 AND par.display_in_parameter_search=1 AND par.hidden=0 
ORDER BY par.sorting, cod.title
```

And i get this error:

> LINE 8: ORDER BY par.sorting, cod.title
>
> ERROR: for SELECT
> DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

I am a total beginner with postgreSQL.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as error message states, par.sorting must be in the select list

if you use distinct or group by, all columns you are sorting by, must be in the select column list

```
SELECT DISTINCT par.id, par.title, cod.id AS id_codebook, cod.title AS title_codebook, par.sorting
FROM catalog_parameter_codebook cod
JOIN catalog_parameter par ON (par.id=cod.id_parameter)
JOIN catalog_parameter_product_value_parameter_codebook_mm codmm ON  (cod.id=codmm.id_parameter_codebook)
JOIN catalog_parameter_product_value pv ON (pv.id=codmm.id_parameter_product_value)
JOIN catalog_product p ON (p.id=pv.id_product)
WHERE p.state=2 AND p.hidden=0 AND par.type=2 AND par.display_in_parameter_search=1 AND par.hidden=0 
ORDER BY par.sorting, cod.title
```

Comment: Ok, I understand it, but when I add par.sorting to the SELECT list, i don´t get a output which required. I get duplicated rows.

Comment: why do you get duplicate? give us a primitive table schema, preferably with a small sampledata, and explain what do you want to acomplish